# Can addressof() be implemented as constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to write a constexpr addressof function, but I find it impossible. Does anyone know if this is possible?

A reference implementation in at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof):

```
template< class T >
T* addressof(T& arg) 
{
  return reinterpret_cast<T*>(
           &const_cast<char&>(
              reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>(arg)
           )
         );
}
```

uses reinterpret_cast (similarly to GCC implementation), so it will not do. I can see that the latest C++ Standard draft, [N3485](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) also does not require that addressof() be constexpr even though lots of functions form header <utility> have ben recently upgraded to constexpr.

A possible, although not very convincing or useful use-case for it would be:

```
constexpr MyType m;
constexpr MyType const* p = &m;           // this works today
constexpr MyType const* p = addressof(m); // this is my question
```

Imagine that MyType has overloaded operator&.

Comment: May I ask why do you need it?

Comment: Addresses of objects are not known compiletime.

Comment: It’s not possible: casts oddly enough cannot be `constexpr`. But I can’t imagine a situation in which a `constexpr addressof` would be needed.

Comment: I am trying to implement a constexpr optional<T> (similar to boost::optional). At some point the addressof is needed in the implementation. See https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/

Comment: Addresses of constexpr objects or parts thereof are also compile-time constants.

Comment: I know it sounds just too easy, and I am likely missing something, but have you tried copying that implementation of `addressof` and putting `constexpr` in front of it? It seems to work for me (see [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/aXP0B$3)).

Comment: @Andrzej This doesn’t itself clearly demonstrate use. Your `optional` needs `constexpr addressof` only in situations where you’re dealing with the address of a `constexpr optional` so you’re merely deferring the question of whether this is useful (I’m not saying that it isn’t, but to be honest I cannot see a use-case for it – that said, I’ve recently come across a case myself that I *want* to solve as `constexpr` but cannot).

Comment: @AndyProwl: It only happens to work in gcc. If you try it with Clang, it fails. According to the Standard (Sect 5.19) reinterpret_cast is not allowed in constexpr functions.

Comment: @Konrad: I need constexpr addressof inside the implementation of optional, in order to implement "normal" operations, like operator->. I admit, I do not know how to present a use case in short, w/o going into too many details.

Comment: Have you considered just using `&`, which apparently is allowed to work in `constexpr` functions? And if they overload `&` for a particular `T`, then simply forbid it from working in a `constexpr` `optional`, or use a non-`constexpr` implementation. That is, condition `constexpr` on a non-overloaded `operator&`.

Comment: @Nicol: Can I easily check if operator& is overloaded? I only know how to check what type it returns, but that would not be sufficient.

Comment: @Andrzej Use two SFINAE overloads to name the member and free `operator&` functions, and one to test whether `&obj` is a valid expression. If the backup overload is taken then `operator&` is not overloaded.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the comments, you can detect whether an overloaded `operator&` is available using SFINAE. And as Potatoswatter points out in the comments, these need to be three separate checks:

1) whether `x.operator&()` is accepted

2) whether `operator&(x)` is accepted

The first two are the two ways a user-provided `operator&` may be defined.

3) whether `&x` is accepted

This third check is necessary because `x.operator&()` may be rejected because `operator&` does exist, but it is private. In that case, `&x` is not valid.

These checks can be implemented by checking `sizeof(f(std::declval<T>()))`, where `f` is overloaded in a way such that the return type depends on whether `T` passes the check.

```
namespace addressof_helper {
  template <typename T>
  static char (&checkaddressof(...))[1];

  template <typename T>
  static char (&checkaddressof(T &&, typename std::remove_reference<decltype(&std::declval<T &>())>::type * = 0))[2];

  template <typename T>
  static char (&checknonmember(...))[1];

  template <typename T>
  static char (&checknonmember(T &&, typename std::remove_reference<decltype(operator&(std::declval<T &>()))>::type * = 0))[2];

  template <typename T>
  static char (&checkmember(...))[1];

  template <typename T>
  static char (&checkmember(T &&, typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<T &>().operator&())>::type * = 0))[2];
}
```

You can then use these helper functions to choose which implementation of `addressof` to use:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<
  sizeof(addressof_helper::checkaddressof<T>(std::declval<T>())) == 2
  && sizeof(addressof_helper::checknonmember<T>(std::declval<T>())) == 1
  && sizeof(addressof_helper::checkmember<T>(std::declval<T>())) == 1,
  T *>::type addressof(T &t) {
  return &t;
}

template <typename T>
/* no constexpr */ typename std::enable_if<
  sizeof(addressof_helper::checkaddressof<T>(std::declval<T>())) == 1
  || sizeof(addressof_helper::checknonmember<T>(std::declval<T>())) == 2
  || sizeof(addressof_helper::checkmember<T>(std::declval<T>())) == 2,
  T *>::type addressof(T &t) {
  return reinterpret_cast<T *>(&const_cast<char &>(reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>(t)));
}
```

This allows `addressof` to be used in constant expressions so long as `operator&` is not overloaded. If it is overloaded, there appears to be no way to reliably get the address in a form that's usable in a constant expression.

Note that GCC 4.7 rejects uses of this `addressof` implementation cases where it should work. GCC 4.8 and higher work, as does clang.

I used a single implementation of `addressof` that forwarded to a helper function in an earlier version of my answer, but I was recently made aware that this is not a good idea, as it can easily lead to ODR violations if `addressof<X>` is used for some class `X` in multiple translation units, in some of which `X` is defined, and in some of which `X` is incomplete. Having two separate functions avoids that problem.

The only remaining problem is that it could fail if `addressof<X>` is used in a translation unit before the definition of `X`'s custom `operator&`. This should hopefully be rare enough that it's not a problem in practice.

Testcases for the sensible examples:

```
class A { } a;
class B { private: B *operator&(); } b;
class C { C *operator&(); } c;
class D { } d;
D *operator&(D &);
extern class E e;

int main() {
  constexpr A *pa = addressof(a);
  /* no constexpr */ B *pb = addressof(b);
  /* no constexpr */ C *pc = addressof(c);
  /* no constexpr */ D *pd = addressof(d);
  constexpr E *pe = addressof(e);
}

class E { } e;
```

Comment: The SFINAE is flawed. It doesn't catch a non-member or private member overload. See my comment.

Comment: The builtin `&` operator is not usable if the overload is inaccessible.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Updated, does this look better to you?

Answer (score 1):

One partial workaround is to define any such object within a `union` wrapper, and pass around pointers to the `union`. The pointer to wrapper can easily be converted to a reference to the type. Pointer arithmetic should work on arrays of wrappers. But I still don't see a way to get a pointer to the type with overloaded `operator&`.

The `union` only needs one member; `struct` would work in practice but in theory an implementation could add padding at the beginning. Not that the padding really makes a difference, if you can't obtain a `MyType *` in a constant expression anyway.

```
template< typename t >
union storage_wrapper
    { t obj; };

constexpr storage_wrapper< MyType > m{{ args_to_MyType_constructor }};
constexpr storage_wrapper< MyType > *p = &m; // not overloaded
```