# Why is the return type of C++ function template instantiations included in the mangled function name?

Tags: c++, name-mangling

The Itanium ABI [specifies](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangle.function-type) that, with a couple uninteresting exceptions, the return type is included in the mangled names of template instantions but not non-templates.

Why is this? In what case could you have two function template instantiations where the linker needs to distinguish them because it is not indicative of a one-definition-rule violation or similar?

As an example of what I mean:

```
class ReturnType {};
class ParamType {};

template <typename T>
ReturnType foo(T p)  {
    return ReturnType();
};
template ReturnType foo<ParamType>(ParamType);

ReturnType bar(ParamType p) {
    return ReturnType();
}
```

Then the resulting object file has manglings:

```
ReturnType foo<ParamType>(ParamType)
   => _Z3fooI9ParamTypeE10ReturnTypeT_
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^

ReturnType bar(ParamType)
   => _Z3bar9ParamType
```

Why does `foo` need `ReturnType` mangled but `bar` doesn't?

(I am presuming there is a reason and it's not just an arbitrary choice.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe because, as opposed to normal functions, a function templates signature contains the return type? §1.3:

> **1.3.17 signature** `<`function`>` name, parameter type list (8.3.5), and enclosing namespace (if any)
>  [ *Note*: **Signatures are used as a
>   basis for name mangling and linking.** — *end note* ]
>
> ---
>
> **1.3.18 signature** `<`function template`>` name, parameter type list (8.3.5), enclosing namespace (if any), **return
>   type**, and template parameter list

Consider that we can have two entirely distinct function template overloads that only differ in their return type, if written thusly:

```
template <int>
char foo();

template <int>
int foo();
```

If name mangling wouldn't consider the return type, linking those templates would prove difficult, since `foo<0>` does not uniquely name one specialization. Still, one specialization can be addressed using overload resolution (without arguments):

```
int (*funptr)() = foo<0>;
```

On the other hand, including the return type is not necessary for ordinary functions, as these cannot be overloaded on their return type - i.e. their signature does not include the return type.

Comment: Really nice example. I was also thinking - could the ODR be violated if the return type was not part of the signature? E.g. if you have the first template in TU 0 and the second in TU 1.

Comment: @dyp Yes, IIRC the declarations must consist of the same sequence of tokens (or an equivalent sequence of tokens, for some definition of equivalent), if they appertain to the same entity.

Comment: I think we might be misunderstanding each other - what I meant was answered more or less in your final paragraph: The name is used for linking, and it *must* contain the return type. Otherwise, the linker might link the first template in declared (not defined) in TU 0 with the second template defined and instantiated in TU 1.

Comment: Your example shows a case where the two template functions are mutually exclusive: for any `T`, `copy<T>` will refer to exactly one of the template functions. You don't need the return type in the mangled name for that. But I posted a (silly) example in my answer where two valid template function instantiations have the same template arguments and parameter types. Can you perhaps come up with a realistic example where that might be useful? I'm having trouble coming up with anything.

Comment: @hvd Ahh, I see what you mean. I.e. the template arguments already uniquely name one specialization. I'll pick another example.

Comment: @hvd I practically stole yours, sorry.

Comment: @hvd Possibly, you could make a function template dependent on the completeness of a type via SFINAE in the return type. In different TUs, the type can be complete or incomplete, which yields two different functions.

Comment: @Columbo Quite alright, but you might actually combine it with your previous example, which is a realistic example of why the standard allows overloading by return type. The non-realistic example in my answer and in your current answer might just be an unfortunate consequence of that.

Comment: @dyp That seems like an example where it actually makes sense, nice!

Comment: @Columbo I found an old example of mine, that I believe is realistic, could be made to be well-formed (with the directions I already noted in my answer), and is exactly the sort of thing that's covered by dyp's comment. Do you think that's a good example, or do you think it would still be undefined with the noted changes?

Comment: The reference to the C++ standard is what I didn't know. Pushes the question to that to some extent, but I think I'm pretty satisfied now. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Template functions may be overloaded by return type alone, unlike regular functions.

```
template <typename T> int f() { return 1; }
template <typename T> long f() { return 2; }

int main() {
  int (&f1) () = f<void>;
  long (&f2) () = f<void>;
  return f1() == f2();
}
```

Here, assuming a non-optimising compiler, the generated assembly will contain two functions `f<void>()`, but they can't share the same mangled name, or there would be no way for the generated assembly for `main` to specify which of the instantiations it refers to.

Typically, if you have an overloaded template function, only one of the definitions will be used for a particular template argument, so this is uncommon, but in the comments on Columbo's answer, dyp came up with the basic idea for how this might actually be useful. In [Can addressof() be implemented as constexpr function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863422/can-addressof-be-implemented-as-constexpr-function), I came up with

```
template <bool>
struct addressof_impl;

template <>
struct addressof_impl<false> {
  template <typename T>
  static constexpr T *impl(T &t) {
    return &t;
  }
};

template <>
struct addressof_impl<true> {
  template <typename T>
  static /* not constexpr */ T *impl(T &t) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T *>(&const_cast<char &>(reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>(t)));
  }
};

template <typename T>
constexpr T *addressof(T &t)
{
  return addressof_impl<has_overloaded_addressof_operator<T>::value>::template impl<T>(t);
}
```

but this is actually an ODR violation if the same instantiation `addressof<X>` is used in multiple translation units, some where `X` is incomplete, and some where `X` is complete and has an overloaded `&` operator. This can be re-worked by performing the logic inside `addressof` directly, using regular overloaded functions.

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<has_overloaded_addressof_operator<T>::value, T *>
addressof(T &t)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<T *>(&const_cast<char &>(reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>(t)));
}

template <typename T>
constexpr
std::enable_if_t<!has_overloaded_addressof_operator<T>::value, T *>
addressof(T &t)
{
  return &t;
}
```

(`has_overloaded_addressof_operator` would need to be inlined too, for the same reason.)

This way, the problem is avoided: when `X` is incomplete, then `addressof<X>` refers to a different function than when `X` is complete.

Comment: But with your changes, a template-id with `addressof` always refers to one specialization uniquely, so this doesn't necessitate a mangling of return types.

Comment: @Columbo `addressof<X>` might refer to the first definition in one translation unit, but to the second definition in another translation unit, for the same `X`. When those translation units can be linked together into a single program, their mangled names need to be different.

Comment: @Columbo I don't see how, can you elaborate? 14.6.4.2 is about what happens if there are other definitions of `addressof` in other translation units, but there are no other definitions of `addressof` in other translation units.

Comment: So your template can basically test whether a class type is complete or not. However, IIRC there has been a lot of discussion about whether such a template is technically possible (across multiple TUs), and the consensus was that its application is ill-formed.

Comment: That deleted comment was referring to a template *in which you use `addressof`*. However, I was unsure whether it was applying, and in hindsight, it does not (the idea was that the definition of addressof in the second TU would be selected, because it would not SFINAE out since `X` is defined in that TU). This still looks uncanny, though.

Comment: @Columbo Oh, I think I see where you're coming from. If you have another template function `f<T>` which calls `addressof<T>`, then `f<X>` must only be instantiated when `X` is a complete type, or `f<X>` must only be instantiated when `X` is an incomplete type. But yeah, as you point out, that's generally a problem even if `f<T>` does not call my `addressof<T>`.

Comment: Yep, that was my thought. However, what about §14.6.4.1/8? *"If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one definition rule (3.2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required."* Two different instantiations of the second template, with template-id `addressof<X>`, might have different results across two TUs. I.e. in one, the instantiation leads to an error, while in the other, there is none.

Comment: According to the ODR §3.2/6.4, *"in each definition of `D`, the overloaded operators referred to […] shall refer to the same function, or to a function defined within the definition of `D`;"*, in your case in one instantiation the `operator&` might be referenced, while in the other, that isn't the case. (This is wrt to the quote in my previous comment, which refers to the ODR)

Comment: @Columbo Normally, the second instantiation won't have any points of instantiation where it would be ill-formed. The only points of instantiation for that second definition should be where SFINAE does not discard that second definition, and at those places, the `&` would be the built-in `&` operator. If any reference is made to `addressof` where `&` would not be the built-in `&` operator, overload resolution / SFINAE is supposed to discard the second definition.

Comment: But the declaration of that template is instantiated (§14.7.1/10). Doesn't that count? :o) If it doesn't, I'm out of ideas, good example.

Comment: @Columbo No, that doesn't count. :) But there is actually an example for what you bring up: 14.6.4.1p8 adds an extra point of instantiation to all templates, at the end of the translation unit, so `extern class A a; void f() { addressof(a); } class A { private: void operator&(); } a;` would be undefined for the reason you give. Overload resolution might pick the `constexpr` version of `addressof<A>`, but its instantiation might be delayed until after the point where `&` is no longer available. I think this is worth mentioning, but rare enough not to cause real problems.

Comment: Wait, does `extern class A { } a;` not define `A`? Also, what you're bringing up is unrelated to your original example, since now addressof is used *before `X` is defined in the same translation unit*. That is clearly ill-formed. :)

Comment: @Columbo I meant `extern class A a;`, sorry. Fixed. But using `addressof<A>` when `A` is only known as an incomplete class type is valid.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. This question (and the last I asked...) makes me wish I could accept both answers, but alas!